# Ocelot with Jwt Auth

Tags: c#, .net-core, ocelot

I'm setting up authentication with jwt auth in ocelot (api gateway in asp.net core), but has not succeeded. I execute my code in postman, but the output is not as expected.

this is ConfigureServices in Startup.cs
I get the ApiKey from appsettings.json, and I add parameter of Jwt like issuer, audience, and IssuerSigningKey.

```
public void ConfigureServices(IServiceCollection services)
        {
            //security key
            string securityKey = Configuration.GetValue<string>("ApiKey:DefaultKey");

            //symmetric security key
            var symmetricSecurityKey = new SymmetricSecurityKey(Encoding.UTF8.GetBytes(securityKey));

            services.AddDbContext<JwtEPDbContext>(options =>
                options.UseSqlServer(Configuration.GetConnectionString("DefaultConnection")));

            services.AddAuthentication(JwtBearerDefaults.AuthenticationScheme)
                .AddJwtBearer(options =>
                {
                    options.TokenValidationParameters = new TokenValidationParameters
                    {
                        ValidateIssuer = true,
                        ValidateAudience = true,
                        ValidateIssuerSigningKey = true,

                        ValidIssuer = "smesk.in",
                        ValidAudience = "readers",
                        IssuerSigningKey = symmetricSecurityKey
                    };
                });

            services.AddMvc().SetCompatibilityVersion(CompatibilityVersion.Version_2_1);
            services.AddOcelot(Configuration);
        }
```

and this ocelot.json

```
{
  "ReRoutes": [
    {
      "DownstreamPathTemplate": "/api/",
      "DownstreamScheme": "http",
      "DownstreamHostAndPorts": [
        {
          "Host": "localhost",
          "Port": 3000
        }
      ],
      "UpstreamPathTemplate": "/api/this-app",
      "AuthenticationOptions": {
        "SecurityKey": "0987654123456qwertysdfgvbniastrtyhajsbc8726ghuaiysdyt1276"
      }

    },

    {
      "DownstreamPathTemplate": "/api/svc_execScript2",
      "DownstreamScheme": "http",
      "DownstreamHostAndPorts": [
        {
          "Host": "10.12.4.155",
          "Port": 990

        }
      ],
      "UpstreamPathTemplate": "/api/test-ep"

    },

    {
      "DownstreamPathTemplate": "/api/svc_execScript2",
      "DownstreamScheme": "http",
      "DownstreamHostAndPorts": [
        {
          "Host": "10.12.4.155",
          "Port": 990

        }
      ],
      "UpstreamPathTemplate": "/api/test-login"

    }

  ],
  "GlobalConfiguration": {
    "BaseUrl": "https://localhost:44319"

  }


}
```

I expect the output is 401 response, but the actual output is 200

Comment: Can you add to the description what your postman request is?

Comment: https://localhost:44319/api/this-app

and i get 200 status ok
but I want to get 401 response, because I don't add bearer token in header

Comment: I think the error is on ocelot.json and startup.cs